# How to compare and merge NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have 2 NSMutableArrays that contains an instances of the class Person. I need to check is there any Person with same value of "name" in both of arrays and merge it with ask about replace instances of Reson with same value "name".

It looks like:

```
empl1 = [
    Person [
        name = @"Paul",
        age = 45,
    ],
    Person [
        name = @"John",
        age = 36,
    ]
]


empl2 = [
    Person [
        name = @"Paul",
        age = 47,
    ],
    Person [
        name = @"Sean",
        age = 30,
    ]
]
```

Then program ask about replacement Person @"Paul" in empl1 with Person @"Paul" in empl2 and add any new persons from empl2 to empl2

And result must be (if we replace Paul):

```
empl = [
    Person [
        name = @"Paul",
        age = 47,
    ],
    Person [
        name = @"John",
        age = 36,
    ],
    Person [
        name = @"Sean",
        age = 30,
    ]
]
```

Think about this 2 days but without success. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement `-isEqual:` and `hash` on Person and put all objects in a Set.

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property NSUInteger age;
@end

@implementation Person

-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherPerson
{
    if([otherPerson isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return [self.name isEqual:otherPerson.name];
    return false;
}

-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.name hash];
}
@end
```

if you now put it into an NSSet or NSOrderedSet just the first object with the same name will be kept. The other will be detected as duplicate and not stored in the set.

For more: [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-SW3)

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *name;
@property NSUInteger age;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(NSUInteger)age;

@end

@implementation Person


-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(NSUInteger)age
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherPerson
{
    if([otherPerson isKindOfClass:[self class]]){
        Person *rhsPerson = otherPerson;
        return [self.name isEqualToString:rhsPerson.name];
    }
    return false;
}

-(NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.name hash];
}

-(NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %lu", self.name, self.age];
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *p1Array = @[[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Paul" age:45] ,
                             [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"John" age:36]];
        NSArray *p2Array = @[[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Paul" age:47] ,
                             [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Sean" age:30]];

        NSMutableSet *resultSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:p1Array];
        NSMutableSet *duplicates = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:p2Array];
        [duplicates intersectSet:resultSet];
        [resultSet addObjectsFromArray:p2Array];

        if ([duplicates count]) {
            for (Person *p in [duplicates allObjects]) {

                NSMutableSet *interSet = [resultSet mutableCopy];
                [interSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithObject:p]];
                Person *pInSet = [interSet allObjects][0];

                NSLog(@"%@ <-> %@", p, pInSet);
                /*
                 Here you have the pairs of duplicated objects.
                 depending on your further requierements, stror them somewhere 
                 and process it further after asking the user.
                 */
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want equality to be strictly name-based elsewhere, sticking the names in a set to quickly determine if you've got a dupe would still be a good solution to this problem.

Comment: This example does not make the most important - a proposal to replace or skip an existing element of the target array

Comment: and how could it? form your question it isnt even clear, if this code is supposed to run on Mac, iOS, CLI… all these would work differently.

Comment: By the way, Your code has error: 'return [self.name isEqual:otherPerson.name];' must be 'return [self.name isEqual:[otherPerson valueForKey@"name"]];'. Anyway Thank You for help!

Comment: In ARC you either do KVC, as you suggested, or you would cast.

Comment: I added a complete example, that should get u going. it will print out the objects identified as duplicates. you can store those and process later regarding your requirements / user input.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use NSSet.

Here's an example:

```
NSMutableArray *temp1 = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSMutableArray *temp2 = @[@4, @1, @5];

NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:temp1];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:temp2];

[set1 unionSet:set2];
```

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
[And here's the documentation of mutable version of NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html).